Returning undefined and NaN
When I call a function using a method, it's returns undefined and Nan.
When it's called counter.increment, it should return the input "init" + 1, counter.decrement should return "init" - 1 and counter.reset should return the initial value of "init". But instead for some reason, the three console.log returns undefined and the function createCounter returns NaN.


var createCounter = function(init) {

  return {

    increment: (init) => {

      console.log(init);
      return init++;

    },

    decrement: (init) => {

      console.log(init);
      return init--;

    },

    reset: (init) => {

      console.log(init);
      return init;

    }

  }

};


const counter = createCounter(5)
counter.increment(); // 6
counter.reset(); // 5
counter.decrement(); // 4




In case you have just missed it or have not taken the full [tour] yet (you earn another badge BTW), there are 100% completely optional actions one can take after someone answers that helps rate and curate content on the site.

Remove init from all the function calls so they correctly use the outer init closed over in scope from the createCounter call. You are trying to update an undefined local init value which results in NaN.
Save the initial init into a local variable that can be mutated.
Note also the console logs are logging the starting value, not the resulting value. It's trivial to capture the result first for logging before returning it.


var createCounter = function(init) {
  let _init = init;
  
  return {
    increment: () => {
      console.log(_init); // (1) 5
      return _init++;     // (1) 5 -> 6
    },
    decrement: () => {
      console.log(_init); // (3) 5
      return _init--;     // (3) 5 -> 4
    },
    reset: () => {
      console.log(_init); // (2) 6
      _init = init;
      return _init;       // (2) 5
    }
  }
};

const counter = createCounter(5);
counter.increment(); // (1) 5
counter.reset();     // (2) 6
counter.decrement(); // (3) 5



Note also that your logic uses postfix ++/-- operators, meaning that the value is returned and then the value is incremented/decremented.
If you desire for the returned value to be the updated value then use the prefix ++/-- operators instead, which increments/decrements first and returns the updated value. Just move the operator in front of the variable you are incrementing/decrementing.


let foo = 5, bar = 5;
// Postfix
console.log(foo++); // 5
console.log(bar--); // 5
foo = 5, bar = 5;
// Prefix
console.log(++foo); // 6
console.log(--bar); // 4



Suggested edit:


var createCounter = function(init) {
  let _init = init;
  
  return {
    increment: () => ++_init,
    decrement: () => --_init,
    reset: () => _init = init,
  }
};

const counter = createCounter(5);
console.log(counter.increment()); // 6
console.log(counter.reset());     // 5
console.log(counter.decrement()); // 4




Wow man, thanks for the help, I didn't know about the prefix "--/++" and now I've noticed that the inner "init" is kind like blocking the outer "init".

@GustavoF.Marcial Welcome, happy to help. Cheers!

EDIT: This answer merely illustrates the problem; for the solution, see @Drew Reese's answer.
Your outer init is not being used, since its being shadowed by the init passed as argument to the inner functions. So to use your code as it is now, you would need to do the following:
[Please don't do this, it defeats the whole purpose of a counter]


/* Do NOT use the following code. It's bad code.
It's only here to illustrate the problem. */

var createCounter = function(init) {
    return {
        increment: (init) => {
            console.log(init);
            return ++init;
        },
        decrement: (init) => {
            console.log(init);
            return --init;
        },
        reset: (init) => {
            console.log(init);
            return init;
        }
    }
};

const counter = createCounter(5); // This value is never used.
console.log(counter.increment(3)); // 3, 4
console.log(counter.reset(8)); // 8, 8
console.log(counter.decrement(2)); // 2, 1



Notice the change of init++ to ++init (and similarly with --init).
Of course, the above code isn't very useful, so to do what you really want to do, remove the init argument of the inner functions, as @Drew Reese shows in their answer.

I think it's wrong to upvote this answer, mainly for 3 reasons: (1) @DrewReese was faster and correct, yet gets less upvotes (2) This answer does (strictly speaking) not solve the problem, it only invents a way to cover the error reason - why on earth would someone want a counter if the counter would only work when every operation is passed a starting value? Why then not use +, - and the value itself (in the case of reset)? (3) To quote: "But to do what you really want [...] do, [...] as @Andrew Reese shows in their answer." (with a wrong "Andrew" Reese).

But more seriously: yes; for anyone reading: please upvote Drew's answer preferentially over this one.

Well, man didn't receive a downvote either, because third party thought the part that explains the variable shadowing is correct. However, having a block of code in an answer usually means that it presents a correct and working solution, but this just bends the rules and makes the whole thing pointless (as I explained it is not a counter, it's { increment: n => n + 1, decrement: n => n - 1, reset: n => n } without internal counter state and therefor still contains the reason that made the OP raise the question), yet makes it look like a real answer for newcomers.



  var createCounter = function(init) {
     
    return {
       increment: () => {
    
       return init++, //The value increases and becomes 6
          console.log(init), //Returns 6
          init-- //Reverses the value back to the original
        }  ,
    
      
    
    
        decrement: () => {
    
         
          return init--, //Value goes down and becomes 4
          console.log(init), //Returns 4
          init++ //Returns to default 5
        
    
        },
    
        reset: () => {
    
          
          return init,//Return Default value
          console.log(init)
         
    
        }
    
      }
    
    };
    const counter = createCounter(5)
    counter.increment(); // 6
    counter.decrement(); // 4
    counter.reset(); // 5




It's not a counter if it's internal state is fixed.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
